# 08001] Could not create connection to database server. Index 5 out of bounds for length 5 - SQL error

Tags: python, mysql, database, homestead, datagrip

I have suddenly started getting this error in my SQL client, and I really do not understand what's going on.

> [08001] Could not create connection to database server. Index 5 out of
> bounds for length 5

The app that I am working on is using Laravel 6, running on Homestead. I can still connect to server DBs, however I now cannot connect to any local DBs. My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 My DB client is Datagrip.

It was working fine until this started, and I haven't changed anything on my OS - I did install the mysql-connector-python package, but in a virtual env. I have uninstalled that and deactivated the venv, but still having the issue.

I am wondering if I've done my virutal env wrong, and the mysql-connector-python package has made an OS change which I'm now unable to fix.

Any help on the matter would be of great help, as I can't find much info about this specific error anywhere.

Comment: So, you can't connect to local MySQL instance? Is it in Docker?

Comment: hi - yeah I can't connect to local MySQL instance. It's in a vagrant box - I have gotten around this issue by creating an SSH connection to the DB, which works fine. 

I'm going to leave this open to see if anyone has a fix, as it would be nice to get to the bottom of this

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect to the Homestead box using the box's IP Address, default MYSQL port, and the default Homestead DB username and password.

192.168.10.10:3306
username: homestead
password: secret

It should work the same with you as well. I'm also on Ubuntu and using Datagrip.